# Why is Netlify .env.NODE_ENV always set to production even though I set it to development?

Tags: netlify

I inherited someone else's project.  They are deploying a reactjs project with Netlify.  I have this environment variable set:

[image]

In my code, I put a `console.log(process.env);`.  After Netlify builds and deploys the website, my browser developer console shows this:

[image]

The Netlify documentation states that `NODE_ENV` is set to `development` by default.  How do I set my environment to `development`?

---

NOTE:

I'm also using `yarn build` to build the project.  I wonder if `yarn build` has rules that ignore my `NODE_ENV` variable and forces environment to be production, as a way to ensure developers never release a dev version?